# how use cross_val_score to predict in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

in my course i learned how to use cross validation to increase the accuracy of my model, everything looks beautiful in training. But when I go to practice in training I find that I can't use the models trained with cross-validation, follow my code:

```
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]


num_folds = 10
seed = 7


kfold = KFold(num_folds, True, random_state = seed)


modelo = LogisticRegression()


resultado = cross_val_score(modelo, X, Y, cv = kfold)


print("Acurácia: %.3f" % (resultado.mean() * 100))
```

in this cross-validation logic how can i use the model trained in my test data?

I'm trying something like `modelo.predict(X_test)` but not success

can anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot predict with `cross_val_score` because in order to predict you need to fit first. You may think though about [sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) which will learn best params through CV and return a fitted model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fit the model to the data before you can use the `.predict` function. I believe you're using scikit learn, so:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X[:2, :])
```

From [scikit documentation here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Comment: this is for training without cross-validation